# Visual Studio 2013 publish error loading CSS, images, js in local IIS (8)

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, publish

I'd been working on this for many hours.

My problem is this -- I can view our web application on both debug and release using IIS Express in Visual Studio 2013.

But when I try to publish it using Web Deploy then load the web app in browser (Chrome) -- it loads but it cannot find the CSS, JS, Fonts and some images.

What may cause this problem? While using Visual Studio 2013 debug or release mode in IIS Express all works smoothly.

Thank you.

Comment: Added to this, the Local IIS I used after publishing is IIS 8

Comment: facing the same problem. if you have found a solution then please do share.

Answer (score 0):

After publish your web application, you must have to change the path of css,images etc.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i have given relative paths and getting same error.